# Name equation and insert it when referring to name?

Tags: math-mode

I have the following matrix (in an equation environment):

```
$$
\mathbf{a}_1 =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1\\
-1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
```

(not sure why the latex is not recognized and formatted)

So I would like to refer to this matrix somehow (maybe a label) but instead of having a link inserted or similar, I would like the actual matrix to be compiled at the place of a reference to this label – is this possible?

I want this because sometimes I am using the same matrix multiple times and it can be frustrating to write the same matrix many times :)

Comment: Don't use `$$`. Use `\[` `\]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `\newcommand` and `\def` are for.

Literally, when the macro is invoked, the definition is replaced into the input stream at that point so that it is "recompiled" as the OP requests.  This means that if the replacement text were a numbered equation, it would take on a different number with each invocation.

First, the case where the substitution is the complete equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myeqn{
\[
\mathbf{a}_1 =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1\\
-1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}\right]
\]
}
\begin{document}
Here is my equation: \myeqn and also here: \myeqn
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then the case where the substitution is only a part of the equation (the vector alone):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myvec{
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1\\
-1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}\right]
}
\begin{document}
Here is my equation: 
\[
\mathbf{a}_1 = \myvec
\]
and also here:
\[
\mathbf{a}_2 = \myvec
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**NOTE:** The advantage of a `\newcommand` over a `\savebox` lies in the fact that the former will adjust for the local environment (since it is recompiled each time), whereas the latter is "fixed".  For example, in a footnote, the size should shrink:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myvec{
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1\\
-1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}\right]
}
\begin{document}
Here is my equation: 
\[
\mathbf{a}_1 = \myvec
\]
and also here in a footnote\footnote{
\[
\mathbf{a}_2 = \myvec
\]
}
\end{document}
```